# how do I get the `id` from a `tr` I leave and a `tr` I'm entering as a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is that I can't get my handlers to update global variables so I can work with them.
I'm making a script that is supposed to "see" when you change a line and add the line you leave to a database.

To do this I need to get the id from both `tr`s and compare them. This is the problem though. I cant make my handlers deliver the data I need.

This is the table that I create dynamically.

```
<tr id="r'.$value['id'].'">
                        <td><input type="text" name="from_date" value="'.$value['db_field1'].'" class="autoupdate r'.$value['id'].'"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="from_date" value="'.$value['db_field2'].'" class="autoupdate r'.$value['id'].' required"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="from_date" value="'.$value['db_field3'].'" class="autoupdate r'.$value['id'].' required"></td>
                    </tr>
```

Here is my jquery.

```
                $('tr td input.autoupdate').on('blur',function(event){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    rid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                    return rid;
                });

                $('tr td input.autoupdate').on('focus',function(e){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    newid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                });

            if ( rid !== newid ) {
                console.log('old id: '+rid);
                console.log('new id: '+newid);
            } else {
                console.log('same row');
            }
```

I have defined `rid` and `newid` outside `$(document).ready(function()`.

Comment: You're setting the variables correctly. The problem is that you're using the variables outside the function, so that code only runs when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Basic He has an `r` prefix.

Comment: why is there a `return rid;` in your event handler ?

Comment: Your code is fine.  You are logging to the console in the document ready handler, before you have focused/blurred a row - therefore you have no data at that point to log to the console.

Comment: Also, in your 2nd event handler you wrote `function(e)`, it should be `function(event)` according to your following code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 var rid='',newid='';
 $('tr td input.autoupdate').on('blur', function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.preventDefault();
     rid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

});

$('tr td input.autoupdate').on('focus', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    newid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    check();
});

function check(){
   if (rid !== newid) {
      console.log('old id: ' + rid);
      console.log('new id: ' + newid);
   } else {
      console.log('same row');
   }
}
```

**[CHECK THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cJjSm/)**

Comment: Not sure you need to call `check()` in the `blur` handler, just the `focus` handler.

Comment: @Barmar Yes you are right. Should be either on blur or focus. Thanks

Comment: this was a big help :D thanks. iv used a little over a day with different script builds and none of em worked. this was the most simple i could make. just needed the check function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events,

```
var rid='',newid='';
$('tr').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    newid = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('mouse leave', newid);
    check();
});

$('tr').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    rid = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('mouse enter', rid);
    check();
});

function check(){

    if (rid !== newid) {
        console.log('old id: ' + rid);
        console.log('new id: ' + newid);
    } else {
        console.log('same row');
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry. i cant use this as the mouse only slows the user down in this. its for a economic "program" for an organisation. ill make a key handler later to catch arrow keys and make shortcuts